# how to copy an element of a string array to another string variable?

Tags: c, arrays

```
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
```

this is what I want to do but it obviously won't work

```
    string key = argv[1];
```

here I want to use the 'key' string as an array of characters to deal with a specific character alone

```
    key = key[1] + 1; 
    printf("%s", key);
}
```

Comment: What is `string`? There is no such type in [tag:c] and actually all "*strings*" in [tag:c] ARE character arrays. So please write a [mcve] and tell us why it isn't working as you want it to. Also, what is `key = key[1] + 1;` supposed to do?

Comment: You say "obviously won't work", but depending on how `string` is defined, that line might work perfectly fine.  How is `string` defined?  Did you define it, or is it defined in some prewritten code that someone gave you?  (It's not defined in C, that much I can tell you.  Were you thinking of the C++ `std::string` type?)

Comment: there is in the library <string.h> @IharobAlAsimi the code was just an example of how I want to use the array of chars, I want to use it as an ASCII number, so in the code I wrote if argv[1] equals 'abc' then key should equal 'b' + 1 or 1 + 1 according to its ASCII number.

Comment: @SteveSummit do you mean this code should work if string is defined?

Comment: @machine_1 I'm doing my best to learn already, sir. I read and try and ask, but I don't know why the community of StackOverflow expects me to be an expert and already know the answer of my own question.

Comment: @FarahRushdy The StackOverflow Community does not expect you to be an expert, but expect you to know the basics.

Comment: I'm in the process, but I do need help through it. @machine_1

Comment: @FarahRushdy No, that's not what I meant.  *If* `string` were defined in a certain way, *that one line* would work.  But there would be other problems.  FIrst we have to know how `string` is defined for you -- do you know?  Also, what do you want `key = key[1] + 1` to do?  If `argv[1]` is the string "cat", what do you want adding 1 to that key to do?

Comment: @SteveSummit I want it to change the character, kinda simple encipher.

Comment: @FarahRushdy If `key` is a modifiable string, then `key[1] = key[1] + 1`, or `key[1] += 1`, or `key[1]++`, or `++key[1]`, will all add 1 to the first character, changing "cat" to "dat".  But of course you'd still have to figure out what you want `z` to change into.  Also you still haven't said if you can tell us how `string` is defined.

Comment: @FarahRushdy No, `string` is not defined in the *string.h* header.

Answer (score 1):

the main function is not well formatted . argv is a 2D array.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

then you can malloc your key variable and use for example the *strcpy* function to copy argv[1] in the key variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int ac, char **av){

    char *key = strdup(av[1]);

    printf("%s", key); 

    free(key)

    return (0);
}
```